# Setting Textbox Value from a Select Statement with $_POST?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm currently trying to create a update type of script where a admin can click a update button, the text that's already in the database is shown in the textboxes & the admin can then replace the text if it's incorrect.

I currently have a error called "Undefined index". This is when i attempt to set a value to my text boxes from my select statement.

This is my current progress,

```
<?php
require 'configure.php';
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
if(isset($_POST['Edit']))
{
    $sql = "UPDATE `pet` SET `pettype` = :petType WHERE id = :id";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $petType = $_POST['petType'];
    $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $statement->bindValue(':petType', $petType);
    $update = $statement->execute();
if($sql)
{
header('location:index.php');
}
}
$jobID = $_GET['id'];
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM pet WHERE petType = "' . $jobID . '"');
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

?>
```

This is my update code, as well as my populate statement at the bottom.

```
<form method="post" action="">
Name:<input type="text" name="petID" value="<?php echo $_POST['petID'] ?>" /><br />
Age:<input type="text" name="petType" value="<?php echo $_POST['petType'] ?>" /><br /><br />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="update" />
</form>
```

This is my Form which i'm using to edit the data.

I've tried

```
value="<?php echo ($pdo['petType']) ?>"
value="<?php echo $stmt['petType'] ?>"
```

Perhaps someone with a little more knoeledge would be able to help. 
Thank you

Comment: *"I currently have a error called "Undefined index"."* - ok, which one(s), what's the full error here?

Comment: ' Notice: Undefined index: jobRef in /srv/http/edit.php on line 37 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0035241144{main}( ).../edit.php:0 " />'

Comment: Also line 38 i assume its where i've attempted to set the value of the text box. 'code' value="<?php echo $_POST['petType'] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value="<?php echo $result['petType'] ?>"
```

But a problem with your code is that you're just inserting the $jobID into the query without sanitizing it. This could lead to sql injection.

Comment: That's fixed the errors thank you, It however doesn't update my database. & is sanitizing important if its just a small project?

Comment: You should always sanitize user input.

Comment: In order to determine why it's not updating correctly, try doing a "var_dump($_POST)" at the top of the page. My guess is that $_POST['Edit'] isn't set.

Comment: It's good practice to sanitize user input? & this is my VAR_dump - array (size=3)
  'jobRef' => string '21' (length=2)
  'jobDescription' => string '45645' (length=5)
  'submit' => string 'update' (length=6)

Comment: It's good practice, plus if anyone else has access they can easily destroy your entire database. As for your var_dump, I was correct; change isset($_POST['Edit']) to isset($_POST['submit']).

Comment: Oh flip i guess i'll have to look into prevention of SQL injections. I've changed that and now my header('location:index.php'); is functioning however it's not actually updating the data as of yet.

Comment: You're using SQL injection prevention in your update; that's what "->prepare" and "->execute" do...you just need to use those for your select statement as well. As for why your post isn't updating, it's likely a problem with your form. Your $_POST var_dump shows jobRef and jobDescription, but your form code doesn't show either of these named inputs. Is there perhaps two forms on the page? They may be in conflict.

Comment: This is my form code : job Ref:<input type="text" name="jobRef" value="<?php echo $result['jobRef'] ?>" /><br />
Job desc:<input type="text" name="jobDescription" value="<?php echo $result['jobDescription'] ?>" /><br /><br />

Comment: I'll implement the prep and execute to my select statement.

Comment: I've resolved it, Lack of sleep is causing silly mistakes :D

Comment: Okay, yeah, in your update you're looking for items named "id" and "petType", but these items don't exist in your form. Your form has elements named "jobRef" and "jobDescription". You either need to update your form, or your update script so that the names match. In other words, the html `<input name="jobRef" />` will translate into the php `$_POST["jobRef"]`.